# Why is the Hayters' way of living described as "...inferior, retired, and unpolished" in "Persuasion"?

Tags: jane-austen, persuasion

When discussing the background of Mrs. Hayter and Mrs. Musgrove in Jane Austen's *Persuasion*, and the difference in the lifestyle of the two sisters, the novel says:

> Mrs. Musgrove and Mrs. Hayter were sisters. They had each had money, but their marriages had made a material difference in their degree of consequence. Mr. Hayter had some property of his own, but it was insignificant compared with Mr. Musgrove's; and while the Musgroves were in the first class of society in the country, the young Hayters would, from their parents' inferior, retired, and unpolished way of living, and their own defective education, have been hardly in any class at all, but for their connexion with Uppercross, this eldest son of course excepted, who had chosen to be a scholar and a gentleman, and who was very superior in cultivation and manners to all the rest.
> <sub>*Persuasion*, chapter 9</sub>

Run-on sentences aside, I'm not sure exactly what "...inferior, retired, and unpolished" is supposed to mean in reference to the Hayters. The preceding lines make it clear that the Hayters weren't necessarily *impoverished*, since Mrs. Hayter "had money" and Mr. Hayter had some property, and the next paragraph indicates that they get along well and the difference in prosperity isn't really a factor:

> The two families had always been on excellent terms, there being no pride on one side, and no envy on the other [...].
> <sub>*ibid.*</sub>

With a statement like that, I find it hard to believe that the Hayters live in a way that makes them deserving of being described as living in an "...inferior, retired, and unpolished" way.

What makes the Hayters' way of living "inferior"? What does "retired" mean in this context, assuming it means something other than "no longer working"? Why is it "unpolished"?

Why are the Hayters described in this way?

Answer (score 1):

The Musgroves are said to be 'in the first class of society'. Of course they are not aristocrats, but they are evidently of quite high social status in the local area.

The Hayters, though not poor, are regarded as being of much lower status and don't have 'polished' manners. Presumably they are described as 'retired' because they don't socialise with the other well-to-do families in the district.

Comment: Can you expand on the matter of ‘polish’? Repeating the same words as the text doesn’t cast a great deal of light. Can you contrast incidents from the book which demonstrate the difference between polished and unpolished? Is there textual evidence for the Heaters’ relative lack of socialising in society?

Comment: @Spagirl - I don't have a copy to hand, but I don't remember there being any scenes of the Hayter family's domestic life. Since no-one else had answered, I was suggesting the most likely meaning of those adjectives in the context of the social milieu that JA wrote about.